# Start recording doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I'm using the recording function from AS, remember it was working a while ago and now everytime I click on "Start Recording", it does nothing and jump straight away to the "Save As" dialog. If I go ahead and save it, results in an empty mp4 file.

I'm using Genymotion by the way and it was working before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use the native `genymotion recorder`,
https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Emulating_sensors_and_features/Capture.htm